# Spring Boot Auditing Hostname and HostIp

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, audit-logging

I have an auditing entity which defined like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Instant;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

/**
 * Base abstract class for entities which will hold definitions for created, last modified, created by,
 * last modified by attributes.
 */
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Instant getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Instant createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public Instant getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Instant lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }
 }
```

And this is the implementation:

```
import com.app.derin.uaa.config.Constants;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Implementation of {@link AuditorAware} based on Spring Security.
 */
@Component
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        return Optional.of(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserName().orElse(Constants.SYSTEM_ACCOUNT));
    }    
}
```

But I also need to store Hostname of request ip ( if it can be acquired from browser/dns if not it can be null) and request ip.

I found some examples and i changed my class to this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Instant;


@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity<T> implements Serializable {

    @CreatedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @CreatedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "created_by",  updatable = false)
    @Embedded
    private T createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant modifiedDate = Instant.now();;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "modified_by")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Embedded
    private T modifiedBy;

    public Instant getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Instant createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public T getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(T createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Instant getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Instant modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public T getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(T modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }
}
```

And my implementation to this:

```
import com.app.derin.configuration.config.Constants;

import java.util.Optional;

import com.app.derin.configuration.ext.AuditorDetails;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


/**
 * Implementation of {@link AuditorAware} based on Spring Security.
 */
@Component
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<AuditorDetails> {

    @Override
    public Optional<AuditorDetails> getCurrentAuditor() {


        AuditorDetails currentAuditor = new AuditorDetails();
        currentAuditor.setLoggedUser(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().orElse(Constants.SYSTEM_ACCOUNT));
        currentAuditor.setHostIp("ip");
        return Optional.of(currentAuditor);
    }


}
```

But if I am right hibernate doesn't support generic types. I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Error setting up or running Liquibase:
[ERROR] org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property com.app.derin.configuration.ext.extendedFields.AbstractAuditingEntity.createdBy has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit targe
t attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What types for T do you have?

Comment: It is for AuditorDetails class, i used it as AuditorDetails or T but it's same. There is no change. This class `import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Embeddable
public class AuditorDetails implements Serializable {
    String loggedUser;

    String hostName;

    String hostIp;

    //getter setters 
}`

Comment: And why do you use T and not AuditorDetails

Comment: It doesn't change anything. T or AuditorDetails. It is not my question. I am asking how to add hostip with audit. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: But your error is that that T is not a known type

Comment: T means generic type, any class could be. Error says Hibernate doesn't support generic and I understand that. If I remove T and replace with AuditorDetails doesn't solve my problem. Same error.  AuditorDetails class is still unkown type for hibernate.  I am looking and asking for alternatives.

Comment: And how does AuditorDetails  look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution and here is how did:

After a lot of googling i found that my problem is with hibernate annotation. I am trying to send Datatype that hibernate doesn't know about. So I changed my class to custom type for hibernate.

More info you can check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types) link. It helped me.

**My AuditorDetails class:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class AuditorDetails implements Serializable {
    private final String loggedUser;

    private final String hostName;

    private final String hostIp;

    public AuditorDetails(String loggedUser, String hostName, String hostIp) {
        this.loggedUser = loggedUser;
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.hostIp = hostIp;
    }

    public String getLoggedUser() {
        return loggedUser;
    }

    public String getHostName() {
        return hostName;
    }

    public String getHostIp() {
        return hostIp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        AuditorDetails that = (AuditorDetails) o;
        return Objects.equals(loggedUser, that.loggedUser) &&
            Objects.equals(hostName, that.hostName) &&
            Objects.equals(hostIp, that.hostIp);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(loggedUser, hostName, hostIp);
    }
}
```

**AuditorDetailsType class:**

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Objects;

public class AuditorDetailsType implements UserType {

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return AuditorDetails.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o, Object o1) throws HibernateException {
        if(o == o1)
            return true;
        if (Objects.isNull(o) || Objects.isNull(o1))
            return false;

        return o.equals(o1);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return o.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] strings, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object o) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String loggedUser = resultSet.getString(strings[0]);

        if(resultSet.wasNull())
            return null;

        String hostName = resultSet.getString(strings[1]);

        String hostIp = resultSet.getString(strings[2]);

        AuditorDetails currentAuditor = new AuditorDetails(loggedUser, hostName, hostIp);
        return currentAuditor;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object o, int i, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (Objects.isNull(o)){
            preparedStatement.setNull(i,Types.VARCHAR);
        }
        else {
            AuditorDetails currentAuditor = (AuditorDetails) o;
            preparedStatement.setString(i,currentAuditor.getLoggedUser());
            preparedStatement.setString(i+1,currentAuditor.getHostName());
            preparedStatement.setString(i+2,currentAuditor.getHostIp());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object o) throws HibernateException {
        if (Objects.isNull(o))
            return null;

        AuditorDetails currentAuditor = (AuditorDetails) o;

        return new AuditorDetails(currentAuditor.getLoggedUser(), currentAuditor.getHostName(), currentAuditor.getHostIp());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) o;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable serializable, Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return serializable;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object o, Object o1, Object o2) throws HibernateException {
        return o;
    }
}
```

**AbstractAuditingEntity:**

```
import com.app.derin.uaa.ext.AuditorDetails;
import com.app.derin.uaa.ext.AuditorDetailsType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Columns;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import java.time.Instant;

@TypeDef(name = "AuditorDetails",
    typeClass = AuditorDetailsType.class,
    defaultForType = AuditorDetails.class)
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity{

    @CreatedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @CreatedBy
    @Columns(columns = {@Column(name = "created_by", updatable = false),
    @Column(name = "created_host_name", updatable = false),
    @Column(name = "created_host_ip", updatable = false)})
    private AuditorDetails createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant modifiedDate = Instant.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Columns(columns = {@Column(name = "modified_by"),
        @Column(name = "modified_host_name"),
        @Column(name = "modified_host_ip")})
    private AuditorDetails modifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "row_status")
    @JsonIgnore
    @ColumnDefault("1")
    private Integer rowStatus = 1;

    protected AbstractAuditingEntity() {
    }
    public AuditorDetails getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public Instant getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Instant createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public AuditorDetails getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(AuditorDetails createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Instant getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Instant modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public Integer getRowStatus() {
        return rowStatus;
    }

    public void setRowStatus(Integer rowStatus) {
        this.rowStatus = rowStatus;
    }
}
```

**SpringSecurityAuditorAware:**

```
import com.app.derin.uaa.config.Constants;

import java.util.Optional;

import com.app.derin.uaa.ext.AuditorDetails;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


/**
 * Implementation of {@link AuditorAware} based on Spring Security.
 */
@Component
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<AuditorDetails> {


    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringSecurityAuditorAware.class);

    @Override
    public Optional<AuditorDetails> getCurrentAuditor() {
        ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest request = sra.getRequest();
        if(request != null) {
            String hostIp = getClientIpAddress(request);
            String hostName = "";
            AuditorDetails currentAuditor = new AuditorDetails(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserName().orElse(Constants.SYSTEM_ACCOUNT),
                hostName, hostIp);
            return Optional.of(currentAuditor);
        }

        return Optional.of(currentAuditor);
    }

    private static final String[] IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES = {
        "X-Forwarded-For",
        "Proxy-Client-IP",
        "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
        "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
        "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
        "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
        "HTTP_FORWARDED",
        "HTTP_VIA",
        "REMOTE_ADDR" };

    public String getClientIpAddress(HttpServletRequest request) {
        for (String header : IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES) {
            String ip = request.getHeader(header);
            log.info("ip : {}", ip);
            if (ip != null && ip.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
                return ip;
            }
        }
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }

}
```